# What is the GETVAL Format in Fortran mixed with C?

Tags: c, fortran

I am running a Fortran code in linux, and somehow it has some functions from C. Now I need to understand how GETVAL works.

I would appreciate if someone can interpret the following.

```
CALL GETVAL('DT ',DT,'R8',0,0,0,0,NDUM,NERR)
```

Comment: I don't think getval is a built-in.  If it's a C function in your code, you'll have to look at the actual source code for that function to interpret it.

Comment: Can you add the interface for GETVAL to your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search in your code (and code of linked libraries) for these symbols:

```
GETVAL
getval
getval_
GETVAL_
getval__
GETVAL__
```

if it is C function called from Fortran is would be defined as one of these in C code, depends on your compiler & flags (e.g. [assume underscore](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-DAEBF260-BE29-4CBD-9417-F774597F9071.htm) for ifort)